# Lost all of my inventory after dying and game crashing, PLR files not helpful

Tags: terraria

Long story short: went to a sky island carrying all of my great items. My wireless keyboard ran out of batteries and due to that I died from a bunch of harpies. Soon after I respawned (with the typical copper tools) the game crashed before I was able to reach the location of my death, where all of my items were. So now I lost several weeks of work on my character just like that.

Is there a way to recover/recreate my inventory? Cheats, editors? I am not familiar with the extra tools the game or the community provides. I can at least get some of my items back from memory. :(

I use Linux. I checked the directory where my saves are stored and all I found were two files - one PLR (player file) and one backup of that file from earlier. Sadly both are post-crash and neither has the location of my death marked on the map (checked) let alone my items (also checked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few options. Online .plr file editors like [Terrasavr](https://yal.cc/r/terrasavr/) might be helpful. Personally I use the [Builder's Workshop](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2440371320&searchtext=builder%27s+workshop) custom world (which has copies of all items) to grab anything I might need. There's versions for each world difficulty (classic/expert/master/journey) if you need them, but you'll need to search the Steam Workshop yourself.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I also found out about **Terrasavr**. Took me some time to get familiar with the UI (not a Terraria expert and the text UI is quite clunky) but I got my things back. Sadly, I still haven't figured out how to apply modifiers but I've already moved forward (with the unmodified items) and managed to get better loot. Perhaps I should have started with Classic and no dropping of items upon dying instead of Expert mode. LOL